# Prove that a square is cartesian

Tags: category-theory

Let $\bf C$ be a category with a subobject classifier $\tau:1\to \Omega$. Let also $a\to x$ and $b\to x$ be two monomorphisms, and call $\chi_a,\chi_b$ the characteristic maps of $a,b$, respectively.

If $\epsilon:e\to x$ is the equalizer of $\chi_a,\chi_b$, how do I show that the square below is cartesian?  $\require{AMScd}$

$$\begin{CD}
e @>>> 1\\
@VV{\epsilon}V @VV{(\tau,\tau)}V \\
x @>{(\chi_a,\chi_b)}>> \Omega\times\Omega\\
\end{CD}$$

Actually my issue is on proving that the square commutes, because at that point the universal property of the pullback follows from the universal property of the equalizer. It seems to me that this is equivalent to prove that $e$ is a subobject of both $a$ and $b$, but even if it feels like a simple task, I really don't see how to do it. Can you just give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: You’re trying to prove something that’s false. Consider the category of finite sets. Let $x = \{0, 1\}$ and let $a = b = \{0\}$ (with the monos being the inclusion map). Then $e = \{0, 1\}$.

Comment: $e$ is like the complement of the symmetric difference of $a$ and $b$: elements of $x$ which are simultaneously in or not in $a$ and $b$. So it's not a subobject of either and the classifying map is not constantly true on $e$.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжевiswithUkraine You’re assuming the category in question is Boolean, which is very often false for toposes. The correct way to describe it would be the subobject $\{w \in x \mid w \in a \iff w \in b\}$, which, in the absence of internal classical logic, is equivalent to neither the pseudo complement of the symmetric difference nor to $\{w \in x \mid (w \in a \land w \in b) \lor (w \notin a \land w \notin b)\}$.

Comment: @Mark Saving "like" in my comment means that I'm thinking of the simplest case of a boolean topos.